# PostgreSQL Query GROUP BY Year/Month - No function matches the given name?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working to write a PostgreSQL query that shows the number of new user signups create by month going back to the start of time in the database. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM users
WHERE users.created_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(users.created_at), MONTH(users.created_at)
```

My goal is to have an output similar to:

```
2019 | August | 500
2019 | July | 444
2019 | June | 333
```

Problem is I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  function year(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 4: GROUP BY YEAR(users.created_at), MONTH(users.created_at)
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
, Time: 0.079000s
```

How can I get this query working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, use `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', u.created_at) as yyyymm, COUNT(*)
FROM users u
WHERE u.created_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would usually use `to_char`

```
SELECT to_char(u.created_at, 'YYYYmm') as yyyymm, COUNT(*)
FROM users u
WHERE u.created_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```